# boost::gregorian input_facet unexpected results

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I have a question regarding reading boost::gregorian::date object from a formatted string. When the input string has the format specified, it works as expected. E.g., the code below

```
std::string fmt = "%Y-%m-%d";
std::string date_str = "2008-10-23";
boost::gregorian::date date;

boost::gregorian::date_input_facet* i_facet(new  boost::gregorian::date_input_facet());
i_facet->format(fmt.c_str());
std::stringstream ss;
ss.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);
ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), i_facet));
ss << date_str;

ss >> date;

std::cout << date << std::endl;
```

produces the correct output.

```
2008-Oct-23
```

However, if the format does not correspond the input string, the streaming of the string into the date object produces wrong results:

`// all the code is the same except input string is as follows:
std::string date_str = "20081023";`

gives 
`2008-Feb-01`,

So, the question is why it produces wrong results instead of throwing an exception, despite the failbit flag is ON?

I have tried to play a bit with different formats and input strings and seems that every mixture of any types of possible delimiters is fine for it unless there are no delimiters at all as in the example above. 
Also, neither looking into the boost  documentation, nor investigating the code itself brought me to the solution.

*Compiled with g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, boost version 1.55

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I agree the behaviour is weird.

What's happening is that the parser never validates the separator characters, at all! Code from `boost::date_time::format_date_parser`:

[image]

Instead the code just skips the input character blindly, assuming it is a separator. This means that in `20081023` `1` is parsed for the `-` in the format specification.

Next up, two digits (`02`) are taken for the `%m` specifier (so, Feb).

Finally, the `3` is parsed for the `-` separator. Apparently, all fields are treated as optional and hence the unspecified day defaults to `1`.

A lot of these things strike me as very very sloppy. I'd write my own parsing here, in a jiffy.

### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e12e622d559e54e6)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct as_yyyy_mm_dd {
    boost::gregorian::date& _into;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, as_yyyy_mm_dd&& manip) {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

        unsigned short y,m,d;
        if (is >> match(
                    uint_parser<unsigned short, 10, 4, 4>() >> '-' >>
                    uint_parser<unsigned short, 10, 2, 2>() >> '-' >>
                    uint_parser<unsigned short, 10, 2, 2>(), 
                    y, m, d))
        {
            manip._into = { y, m, d };
        }

        return is;
    };
};

int main() {
    boost::gregorian::date date;

    for (auto input : { "20081023", "2008-10-23" })
    {
        std::cout << "Parsing: '" << input << "' ";
        std::stringstream ss(input);
        //ss.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);

        if (ss >> as_yyyy_mm_dd{ date })
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << date << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Parsing: '20081023' Parse failed
Parsing: '2008-10-23' Parsed: 2008-Oct-23
```

Comment: Added a live demo of a simple manual parser: **[`as_yyyy_mm_dd`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e12e622d559e54e6)**. Of course this will hurt if you need dynamic formats. By all means, drop a bug report at the mailing list (I think this counts. It could even lead to security vulnerabilities, even though that would be largely the responsibility of the person testing his usage :))

Comment: Thanks, for the profound answer. For now, I stay with the parsers like you just proposed. If I need more complicated - will try to switch to regex's.

Comment: @pausag that sounds a bit upside down. This, you could still pull of using regex. If you need more complicated, a parser generator like Spirit will become desirable. Anyways [me writing that parser live](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/a-yyyy-mm-dd-gregorian-date-parser-that-works/) ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))